# Gostaria de alterar um atributo de um elemento dinâmico com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que pensei que funcionaria, porém nada acontece:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tab-departamentos a', function(){
  $('textarea').each(function(){
    var a = (this.scrollHeight-12)/20;

    //alert(a);

    $(this).attr('rows', a);
  })

  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(href).tab('show');
})
```

o link `#tab-departamentos a` serve para mostrar o conteúdo de uma [Tab do Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) (assim: `$(href).tab('show')`).

Mas só consigo editar o atributo `rows` da Tab principal, as outras que estão ocultas e são elementos dinâmicos não são alterados.

Comment: Apesar de você ter alegado que o código é pequeno, criar o fiddle ajudaria o restante das pessoas a entender o contexto completo do seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Testei aqui e parece estar funcionando...

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#tab-departamentos a', function () {
        $('textarea').each(function () {
            var a = (this.scrollHeight - 12) / 20;
            alert(a);
            $(this).attr('rows', a);
        });

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        //$(href).tab('show');
        alert(href);
    });
```

Ou qual era exatamente a parte que não funcionou?
Apresentou algum erro no console?

Só não testei o panel, o resto está funcionando aparentemente..

Comment: esse link aqui (#tab-departamentos a) serve para mostrar o conteúdo de uma Tab do Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) assim ($(href).tab('show')), o que ocorre é que só consigo editar o atributo rows da Tab principal, as outras que estão ocultas e são elementos dinâmicos não são alterados...

Comment: não aparece erro no console, mas só altera o Panel ativo entende?

Comment: Entendo mas não tenho como simular aqui a mesma situação para tentar te ajudar....

Comment: Tá blz Rafael, vlw a tentativa, tentei inclusive duplicar a minha funçãozinha no call back do fade-in mas não deu certo...